# compare arraylists of chars alphabetically

Tags: java

I've got my own class `word` and `symbol`. `Symbol` is some wrapper for char. `Word` is an  `ArrayList<Symbol>`.
I need to sort `ArrayList<Word>` by number of occurrences of some `symbol` or if number of occurrence is the same - alphabetically. 
How to do it? I think I need to override `compareto` method of class `Word` and then use `Collections.sort`. 
But I don't know how to compare two `words`(two arraylists) alphabetically.

Here is part of `symbol` class

```
public class Symbol implements Comparable<Symbol> {
    private char symbol;
    ....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Symbol o) {
        return Character.valueOf(symbol).compareTo(Character.valueOf(o.getSymbol()));
    }
}
```

And here is the part of `word` class

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

    private ArrayList<Symbol> word;
    private Symbol comparable_symbol;

    public int count(){ //number of occurrences
        int count = 0;
        for(Symbol s:word){
            if (s == comparable_symbol) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        int left = this.count();
        int right = o.count();
        if (left == right){
            //compare alphabetically
        }
        else return (left > right)?1:-1;
    }

}
```

How to compare two arraylists alphabetically?

Comment: Simply compare each character value from left to right? If one word is shorter than it preceeds the other one if all the previous characters match. Of course, this will use Unicode 16 bit code points as the alphabet unless you make additional changes...

Comment: A very bad trick would be to regenerate a `String` instance using a `StringBuilder` and compare the strings, but if this is an assignment you may get clobbered for that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (word.contains(comparable_symbol)){
    // Add to a new list
}
if (newList.size() > 1){
    // Sort your list alphabetically
}
```

You would also have to implement and override compareTo(Word o) to get word.contains(comparable_symbol) working correctly.