# Comparison method violates its general contract(arraylist comprasion)

Tags: java

I asked before [compare arraylists of chars alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429431/compare-arraylists-of-chars-alphabetically) how to compare arraylists of chars alphabetically. 
Now I decided to implement it.

Here is my comprasion method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Word o) {

    int left = this.count();
    int right = o.count();

    if (left == right){
        if (this.length() > o.length()){
            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < this.length(); i++){
                    if (this.get(i).compareTo(o.get(i)) < 0)
                        return 1;
                }
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                return -1;
            }
        }

        else {
            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < o.length(); i++){
                    if (this.get(i).compareTo(o.get(i)) < 0)
                        return -1;
                }
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else return (left > right)?1:-1;
    return 0;
}
```

I check whether `this.count` is equal to `o.count` and if not I begin to compare every element of arraylists. But if it is not equal then I compare `left` and `right`.

But I don't understand why it throws such exception. Where is the problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at task.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

`Main.java: 69` is where `Collections.sort` invoked`.

Comment: It might help if you provide the actual exception you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

```
if (this.get(i).compareTo(o.get(i)) < 0)
    return 1;
```

This should return -1

```
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    return -1;
}
```

This 1 (since `this` size is bigger)

```
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    return 1;
}
```

This -1 (since `this` size is smaller)

Try with these changes..